# Scheduled Startup C# Application can't show Forms for Logged-in Users

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-xp

I've been working on an application for Windows XP that needs to startup with admin level rights at the same time Windows starts up, so I went ahead and added the exe using Task Scheduler to "Run at system startup".

There should never be more than one instance of the application running at any given time. Ideally, the application would start when Windows boots-up, then no matter which user logged in or if users logged out and logged in through the course of the day, my application would always be running in the background. That way, even if users are switching using "Fast User Switching", my application will stay running from user to user.

All of this seemed to work correctly to a point. However, occasionally my application needs to display a Form or interact with the user in some way and this is where it breaks down. Forms don't show up (though I believe they are running). If I use the Process class and try to execute programs, they show up in the Task Manager as running but they don't actually display. They don't list any handles in Process Hacker when examining them either. It's like they're just running silently in the background.

I can't just change the task to run on User Login for a number of reasons. One, I'm pretty sure I would have to add the scheduled task to every user. Two, there should only be one instance of this program running, and I'm afraid if somebody used Fast User Switching, then two instances of the program would get run. Even if I detected that one instance was already running it wouldn't fix the problem since the instance #1 for user #1 couldn't show forms/windows for user #2 (I don't think, correct me if I'm wrong on this point though.)

Ideally, I'd like to keep with it running at system startup and just figure out why I can't display any windows.

Couple notes about the program, it doesn't initially show anything when it first starts up. It creates a form

```
WndHidden wnd = new WndHidden()
```

but then just runs `Application.Run()` without passing the form in, and then just waits for certain system cues for when to display forms/messages to the user.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: might be helpful: http://serverfault.com/questions/458848/can-i-schedule-a-windows-task-to-run-in-an-interactive-desktop-session

Comment: Under which user account the exe runs ?

Comment: It runs as "AdminUser" which is the sole admin account on the computer, everyone else is a limited user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you have quite a situation here. You want your process to run at startup, even when no user is logged in. again you want the process to show a form on the screen. now that conflicts! for a form can be shown on some logged in user's desktop. no user - no desktop - no form.

Every process belongs to some user. if no user is logged on then the process belongs to SYSTEM . every user has own desktop. a logged in user has a real desktop, SYSTEM has a virtual desktop. so, your forms are being showed but not on the real desktop, but on a virtual desktop. hence you cannot see it.

A process cannot meddle with some other user's desktop. so your process cannot show form on other users or users logged through fast-switching.

If you forget about the fast-user-switching part and be content with only one user, then while scheduling it you can specify that specific user's credentials. that way you get what you want except the multi-user scenario. but beware, if the user changes password then the scheduled task breaks. you have to re-schedule it.

---

What you want is the behavior shown by most of the anti-virus software. you need **2** executables. (it can be done with one exe, but let us not complicate the matters) make first process run at startup before any user logs in. run it with usual SYSTEM account. if possible register the process as windows-service, rather than a scheduled task. dont put any user-interface logic in the process.

put all UI logic in the second executable. register the second executable to run at startup of every user. dont show any forms beforehand. better make a tray-icon project. lay dormant in every user's desktop.

your master process is single and independent of users. the per-user slave processes hold the UI. the trick is to pass signals from master to corresponding slaves. set up a communication medium, sort of IPC (inter process communication). the master will get notification the moment a slave comes online. the master can even choose which slave (user) to ask to show the forms. this mechanism works even when multiple users are logged in simultaneously through remote desktop.

---

As for IPC, you can choose from a wide range. options are: 1. TCP/IP, 2. Named pipe, 3. WCF (tcp/named-pipe), 4. Remoting.

if the names above are unfamiliar then i suggest go with plain TCP/IP, but try and upgrade the communication to WCF as soon as possible.

What you are trying to accomplish is actually way much complicated than it looks. in XP this would have been easy but this is why XP was more susceptible to malware and viruses then Vista+. feel free to ask again.

Comment: Thanks inquisitive, just to provide clarification, the process now runs as Admin since those are the credentials assigned through task scheduler. What if I rewrote the program as a service? Would that restrict it to running just a single instance and could it show forms?

Comment: as a service, it would run as single instance, but no forms. though services *can* be made to present forms, but in practice it never helps. the 1-service-*n*-user-agents is the long but most flexible and stable solution.